# Fill a slice with field pointers of a struct

Tags: go, struct, slice

I'm creating a function which receives an `interface{}`, which will always be a struct, but it could be any struct.

I need to fill one slice with pointers of all the fields of the struct received. The place in the code below where I need to pick the field pointer is flagged with `**FIELD POINTER**`

My final goal is create a function to receive a **struct** equivalent to the return of the query sent in the parameter **sqlQuery**. I want to create a dynamic function to perform any type of query to select, always using the struct received for `.Scan`.

It may be that I'm thinking the wrong way, I'm still starting Golang.

```
func QuerySelect(entity interface{}, sqlQuery string) {
    val := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(entity))
 
    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+
        "password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        host, port, user, password, dbname)

    // Validate database params
    db, err := sql.Open(driver, psqlInfo)

    // If returned any error
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Validate connection with database
    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Execute query
    rows, err := db.Query(sqlQuery)

    countColumns := val.Type().NumField()

    var allRows []interface{}

    for rows.Next() {
        columnsPointers := make([]interface{}, countColumns)

        for i := 0; i < countColumns; i++ {
           columnsPointers[i] = **FIELD POINTER (entity struct)**
        }

        if err := rows.Scan(columnsPointers...); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        allRows = append(allRows, entity)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://play.golang.com/p/CCzvpnZSOLQ is this what you looking for?

Comment: @mkopriva So, I tried to use `.Addr()` just now, but your return is not accepted by `.Scan()`. It returns the following error:  `sql: Scan error on column index 0: destination not a pointer`

Comment: My bad, `Addr` still wraps that pointer in a `reflect.Value` and returns that, so to make it a valid argument for scan you need to "unwrap" it, ie get the value contained in the `reflect.Value`, to do that you can call the `Interface` method on that. i.e. `val.Field(i).Addr().Interface()`

Comment: @mkopriva that was it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Per  mkopriva's commentary on the question, use the following to get the address of the field:

```
for i := 0; i < countColumns; i++ {
   columnsPointers[i] = val.Field(i).Addr().Interface()
}
```